# Parse a string in a textfile with php

Tags: php, parsing, text

I am using cURL to obtain a cookie and in the cookie flie there is a key that looks like this `23da0280fceca40a8601a13f8659a47001417692` I need to parse the key, but I dont think dom parsing is the way to go could be wrong. What could be the best way to get this string? So far I have the following code

```
$Cookie_Key = file_get_contents ('cURL_Cookie.txt');
echo $Cookie_Key;
```

In the text file there is the following line

```
www.box.com FALSE   /   FALSE   145676961   key_57520   23da0280fceca40a8601a13f8659a47001417692
```

I need to obtain the last part `23da0280fceca40a8601a13f8659a47001417692`

Comment: Parse it how? which parts do you need ?

Comment: i added what is in the text file

Comment: would regex be appropriate here?

Comment: Will the contents of this file grow or change over time?

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that the format will always be the same - something as simple as this:

```
$string = "www.box.com FALSE   /   FALSE   145676961   key_57520   23da0280fceca40a8601a13f8659a47001417692";

$key = array_pop(split(' ', $string));

echo $key;
```

should do

Answer (score 0):

```
// File contents:
// www.box.com FALSE   /   FALSE   145676961   key_57520   23da0280fceca40a8601a13f8659a47001417692

$Cookie_Key = file_get_contents ('cURL_Cookie.txt');
$words = preg_split("/\s+/", $Cookie_Key);

// It's the 6th item in the array.
$key = $words[5];
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you will like this one, easy and neat! :)

```
$Cookie_Key = preg_replace('/\s\s+/', ' ', $Cookie_Key);
preg_match("/key_57520 (?P<ckey>[a-zA-Z0-9]+)/", $Cookie_Key, $matches);
$Cookie_Key_Value = $matches[ckey];
```

Comment: What will happen if the string key_57520 changes? From what I see in the question, the only sure thing is that the key is last, file contents changes every time. Plus, why bother firing up the regex engine when a simple strings can be used?